# Python to csv with append - continuous numbering

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am looping through a number of pages and extract 500 datapoints per page. Now, I am printing the output to a csv file using the ".to_csv" function and the append (mode = a) method to add the 500 entries after each page. All of that works fine. 
My problem is: python creates a No. column (numbering each row 0,1,2,..). With the append function is starts from 0 again for each new set of 500 datapoints. The questions is: how can I make python use continuous numbering (i.e. 501 datapoint is 501 instead of 0)?

```
Dataset.to_csv('[path]' + File_name, sep=';', encoding = 'utf- 
8', mode = 'a')
```

Comment: `df.index = df.index + 500 * page_num`

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question, but I am not sure why you actually need the index. You can remove the index from your csv file and save a bit of space. Just use from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html#pandas.Series.to_csv):

```
Dataset.to_csv('[path]' + File_name, sep=';', encoding = 'utf- 8', mode = 'a',index=False)
```

Comment: In addition to @BenT's comment, maybe you can add a new No. column and increment it yourself.